# Batch file asks infinite times for input

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off

:cancel

    shutdown /a

:shut

    set a=%1

    shutdown -s -f -t %a%

cls

set /p a="the computer will shut in:" %=%

set /a a=%a%*60

if %a%=="a" call :cancel

pasue

call :shut

pause
```

It is supposed to ask the user for a number. It will take the number and shutdown the computer in x minutes (I Multiplied by 60 to convert to seconds), if the answer is "a" it will cancel the shutdown.
When I start the program, it is asking me infinity times for input and doesn't call shutdown at all
Thanks :)

Comment: Use `Ctrl+K` or the `{}` button to format codes (select first).

Comment: Do you mean I need to do {shutdown -s -f -t %a%}?

Comment: No, I mean how to format the post here, to make it looks right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at your code, I guess, you're confusing "labels" with "Function declarations". There are no functions in batch (at least not like in other languages), just `call`, `goto` and "labels"

For the shown task, you don't need any labels at all:

```
@echo off
set /p a="the computer will shut in:" %=%
if /i "%a%"=="a" shutdown -a & goto :eof
set /a a*=60
shutdown -s -f -t %a%
```

(Note: you had a logical failure in your code: `set /a` always returns an Integer (as long as it doesn't produce a syntax error), so it doesn't make sense to compare the variable with the string `a` *after* the `set /a`)

Recommended read: [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515901/where-does-goto-eof-return-to)

Comment: Well, the `function` is just a concept, since there're parameters, call and returns, so it can be called `function`. Well, maybe more like `procedure` than function :)

Comment: @Tiw: yes, it can be used like a function or procedure, and all of us do that (a lot) and even call them functions sometimes, but technically, it isn't. (My personal favorite term is "Subroutine")

Comment: I agree, and like your term "Subroutine" :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
::It's better to comment out @echo off, and only when the .bat works fine and then use it.
::@echo off

cls
set /p a="the computer will shut in:"
::You'll need to put %a% inside quotes too, otherwise it can't be equal when you input a.
if "%a%"=="a" call :cancel & goto :eof

:: equals to set /a a=a*60, and with /a you don't need %
set /a a*=60

:: You forgot the parameter. And the goto :eof is necessary
call :shut %a%
pause && goto :eof

::You need to put functions at last.
:cancel
    shutdown /a
    goto :eof
:shut
    set a=%1
    shutdown -s -f -t %a%
```

The main problem in your code is the execution flow.
When there's no switch or `goto`s, it will execute commands from first line to the last line.
(That's why it asked you infinite times, because every time you `call :cancel`, it will execute from `:cancel` function to the `set /p` again.)

You need to put functions below the main codes.
And in the functions, you need to add `goto :eof`(except the last line since it's alreay **e**nd **o**f **f**ile).
And after the function calls you need add `goto :eof` too.

Comment: @אבירוז  **E**nd **o**f **f**ile, which means to exit current batch executing.

Comment: I found the problem. I forgot to give parmeter to shut: